# Return null if no records found in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have below query which is not returning any rows

```
SELECT branch, acno, custno 
FROM ac_master 
WHERE branch = 9
```

How do I return null  as a result?

Expected result:

```
branch acno custno
-------------------
null   null null
```

Comment: Is `branch` unique? i.e. is the maximum number of rows that can be returned one? If that is the case then `select MAX(branch) AS branch,MAX(acno) AS acno,MAX(custno) AS custno from ac_master where branch=9`

Comment: This is a really odd requirement, why would you need to return anything if there are no matching rows?

Comment: Why dont You use IF clause, something like ,
IF EXISTS ( SELECT branch, acno, custno 
FROM ac_master 
WHERE branch = 9)
BEGIN
    SELECT branch, acno, custno 
FROM ac_master 
WHERE branch = 9
END
ELSE
  SELECT NULL as branch , NULL as acno , NULL as custno

Comment: agree with davidg. what you describe is returning a single row with all values set to null which doesnt make much sense

Comment: my actual query is ``` with block as ( select * from blc),hrk as (select * from ac_master) select a.blockcode,b.* from block a left join main b on a.Brcode=b.branch

Comment: The consumer of your resultset should be sufficiently intelligent to respond properly to an empty resultset. Alternatively, use your BRANCH table (which presumably you have) and outer join.

Answer (score 3):

It's an *odd* format, but you could use a `VALUES` table construct with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT m.branch,
       m.acno,
       m.custno
FROM (VALUES(NULL))V(N)
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ac_master m ON m.branch = 9;
```

This'll return a single row, of 3 `NULL`s, if the `LEFT JOIN` to `ac_master` returns no rows.

Though I don't disagree with DavidG's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68995693/return-null-if-no-records-found-in-sql-server/68995793#comment121939020_68995693) that this is an odd requirement.

Comment: As you are only selecting from `m`, there is no need for `V` to have any particular number of columns as long as it has exactly one row. Using three suggests the schema should match `ac_master`, which is not the case (it might be for other approaches). (Also, this is not valid as written since the `VALUES` clause now specifies three rows of one column each, not one row with three.) In short, `(VALUES (NULL)) _(_)` would suffice.

Comment: You're right, @JeroenMostert, I just "auto-piloted" to making it three columns as that was what the OP had. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet (I'm only half way through my first mug). :)

Answer (score 0):

The query that @larnu gives is faster from some other solutions like this one :

```
WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT branch, acno, custno 
FROM   ac_master 
WHERE  branch = 9
)
SELECT * FROM T
UNION  ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T);
```

If the cardinality of the result is low (generally under 10 000 rows).

I tested it over 1, 1000 and 1000000 rows and the query cost results are above ;

1 row : 40% @larnu 60% @sqlpro

1000 rows : 43% @larnu 57% @sqlpro

1000000 rows : 52% @larnu 48% @sqlpro